# Убрать эхо из аудиозаписи

Tags: аудио, поиск-программ

Есть аудиозапись, в которой часть выступления с микрофоном, а часть - без.

Хотелось бы убрать эхо от микрофона, чтобы остался только голос.

Как это можно сделать?

Фрагмент записи, в котором первые 10 секунд с эхом, а следующие - без:
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/SiRm/YXDVYFtX9

Comment: https://www.wikihow.com/Remove-Echo-from-Audio

Comment: @edem, вроде это инструкция для фонового шума, а не эхо?

Comment: Native Instruments Reaktor, но даже не спрашивай как им пользоваться 

Answer (score 1):

В Audacity попробуйте обработать запись фильтром типа Noise Gate.